# CSE Formula to count UNICODE value of a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a string let's say "Adam". The formula must withdraw UNICODE value of  each character and sum it up. This must be done using CSE(Array formulas). Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far plz?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could go:

1. build 3 columns with input:

   - A: index to help decompose the Name your working on
   - B: letters
   - C: UNICODE value you will add up for your result;
2. then first formula takes the name and uses `MID` function with increasing index to decompose each letter in column E; write `=MID($D$2;C2;1)` in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>, then drag formula to the bottom of your sheet.
3. second formula uses `VLOOKUP` to take the UNICODE value associated in the green table to the name's letter; write `=IF(E2<>"";VLOOKUP(E2;$B$2:$C$14;2;FALSE);0)` in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>, then drag formula to the bottom of your sheet. - note the use of `$` to express a fixed cell, and no `$` to express a relative position in the formula
4. Result is the sum of column described above.

Here is what you should have (I let you, if I may, complete the UNICODE list values for letters):

[image]

Hope it helps.